# ActiveRecord to fetch data from 2 tables by joining using find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I know that there're some ways to join/include tables, but here I'd like to retrieve data from 2 tables by using ActiveRecord.find_by_sql.

*Example)*
There are 2 tables.

```
Table1: User{
id: Integer
name: String
}
Table2: UserComment{
id: Integer
user_id: Integer
comment: String
}
```

Now what I want ActiveRecord to retrieve is

```
select u.name, count(uc.comment) from User u, UserComment uc where u.id = uc.user_id group by u.name
```

How can we write this with ActiveRecode? Below only return u.name :(

```
User.find_by_sql(<<-SQL)
select u.name, count(uc.comment) from User u, UserComment uc where u.id = uc.user_id group by u.name
SQL
```

One possible way is to run SQL directly by using Base.connection.execute? Umm, but it doesn't look coolest.

```
sql = 'select u.name, count(uc.comment) from User u, UserComment uc where u.id = uc.user_id group by u.name' ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Possibly, better to run SQL directly?
sql = 'select u.name, count(uc.comment) from User u, UserComment uc where u.id = uc.user_id group by u.name'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you have a `has_many :user_comments` association defined in your `User` model:

```
User.joins(:user_comments).group(:name).count
```

Comment: Thanks spickermann for the comment. How about when we have 'order by' for the result of .count? Let's say order by sum(uc.comment)?